# Issue with symlinks and file uploads

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload, symlink

I'm having this weird thing happen. My Zend Framework (PHP) web application that I have been developing locally works fine on my computer, but once it's uploaded to the server, it thinks that the uploads directory doesn't exist.

My application has an uploads directory which is a symlink to a directory outside of the application:

```
#local
/myapp.local
    /application
    /data
        /uploads (symlink, points to ./../../shared_uploads)
    /public/index.php
/shared_uploads

#remote
/shared_uploads
/current (symlink, points to ./releases/myapp-2009-12-18)
/releases
    /myapp-2009-12-18
        /application
        /data
            /uploads
        /public/index.php
```

The server points to `/current/public/index.php` to serve up the application. Could it be that since it is actually in the releases directory that it's one level deeper? Or could it be a permissions error since I created the uploads symlink on my local computer instead of on the server?

**Update:** In my `/public/index.php` file I'm defining my upload dir like this:

```
// Define path to uploads directory
defined('APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR')
    || define('APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../data/uploads'));
```

Comment: I don't see `/current/public` in your directory tree description...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions shouldnt be an issue so long as your `UMASK` is `0022` but the question is how are you uploading? FTP isnt going to respect a symlink (though i beleive sftp does) while scp or rsync will.

Whit that said though its definitely your directory structure nesting. the symlink is should be relative from the true location of its parent so in your case thats going to be `ln -s ../../../../shared_uploads`. i think the easiest solution here would be to make a symlink within `releases` to refer to the real `shared_uploads`.

Comment: I added the symlink in releases, and that did the trick! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
defined('APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR') || define('APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR', dirname(dirname(realpath(__FILE__))) . '/data/uploads');
```

I removed the `..` by using two `dirname()`s and I ran `realpath()` earlier to remove the symlink from the path.

Though I suspect you don't need the `realpath()` at all.

Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

Using Transmit FTP app there is a checkbox when you sync "Follow symbolic link" that seems to work for me.